# iOS: What is the grouped tableView header/footer text default style

Tags: uitableview, header, styles, footer, nsattributedstring

This problem sometimes bothers me a lot. For example, if I just want to change the header text font size, I have to create the whole UIView. There is no direct instance method for UITableView like [tableView setHeaderTextFont], I think apple should really add this method.

However, [this post](http://www.gersh.no/posts/view/default_styling_of_sections_headers_in_uitableview_grouped) did a good job, but it's not exactly the same with the original one. If you check the original one very careful, it has effect like 'inner glow' in photoshop, but with **NSAttributedString**, this can not be done **(correct me if I'm wrong).** It must be rendered by some private methods.

Also, the footer text style is the same.

So my question is: how to recreate the grouped tableview header/footer text style, exactly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're talking about is just a 1px white shadow. It's there in the post you linked to:

```
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
```

Are you implementing this and not seeing the effect?